"Robert had suggested he invite her to his graduation . . ."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 11)

Robert had suggested he invite her to his graduation, telling William that he and Evelyn had exchanged letters over the past few months; friendly, open.

I think would/should is missing there and it has to be . . .
Robert had suggested he would/should invite her to his graduation . . . , right? However, invite could be a subjunctive there, or, maybe, the whole thing is a typo.

The form of the verb is not marked for number (he invite). This signals that "he invite her" is not a declaration of fact but is, here, a suggestion that Robert made concerning what he thought  might be good or advisable for the other person to do.  should is another way of indicating much the same thing, although perhaps with a bit more urging behind it.

My goodness. Tons of  learners do not know how to use recommend, advise and suggest (and a few others). So, why downvote this? Unbelievable.

Robert had made a suggestion to invite her... I think this means basically the same thing  except that it's a little less stiff and formal.

@shawnt00 I dunno, English is better with verbs than a longer phrase. Not sure suggest + verb is more formal. It is just the grammar for that verb.

You may be an authority here. I don't really know by what sense you would argue better--beyond word count. Either way I just thought it facilitated understanding the meaning by a more typical construction. I thought about your answer but I don't much imagine anybody under 30 writing that on Instagram. They'll almost certainly inflect the verb even then.

Adding would or should changes the meaning. That said, this pattern is used with these verbs. The bare or base form of the verb is used.
Pattern: verb of suggestion + that + subject + base verb
Examples:

My friend recommended that John take a taxi home from the party.
The sales clerk suggested that Mary put the dress on hold.
Martha is
advising that we finish our project today.
When verbs with the general meaning of “suggestion” (including
advise, ask, demand, insist, prefer, propose, recommend, request, suggest, and urge) are used with a noun clause, we must use a base
verb. The noun clause usually starts with the word that and contains
a subject, base verb, and possibly an object. The noun clause usually
occupies the object position of the main sentence: S + V + (that + S +
V + O).

How to use recommend, advise, suggest
There are other patterns in that link but this one is related to this question. These verbs take a second verb that is a base verb.
This: Robert had suggested he invite her to his graduation. = YES.
Present tense examples also work:

He suggests she leave now.
They recommend he stay put.
I advise it be turned off.

